# Updating multiple values in redux

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux

I'm trying to update a nested object in redux but I'm not quite sure if I'm doing it correctly. The code provided below doesn't compile as there's a syntax error in the reducer.

I understand it's not the right syntax as there's no key before `action.payload` but I'm lost in terms of how I merge the action.payload into the [action.id].

I'm trying to avoid creating individual actions for every key I need to update (e.g. `updateBlockType`, `updateBlockTitle`, `updateBlockDescription`, etc.)

**Dispatch:**

```
this.props.dispatch(updateBlock(this.props.id, { type: e.currentTarget.id }))
```

**Action:**

```
export function updateBlock (id, values) {
  return {
    type: 'UPDATE_BLOCK',
    id: id,
    payload: values
  }
}
```

**Reducer:**

```
case 'UPDATE_BLOCK':
  return {
    ...state,
      blocks: {
      ...state.blocks,
      byHash: {
        ...state.blocks.byHash,
        [action.id]: {
          ...state.blocks.byHash[action.id],
          action.payload <-- How do I merge the payload?
        }
      }
    }
  }
```

**byHash[id] object:**

```
'1': { id: 1, type: 'INTRO', title: 'Some title...', description: 'Some description...' }
```

My way of structuring my reducer might be wrong, so I'm open to how else I should tackle this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You missed the spread operator : `...action.payload` which will spread the properties of the payload which is an object to the object entry in reducer

If the structure gets more complex, it is better to compose reducers to sub-reducers and merge them with thr `combineReducers` api from redux.

Also you are accessing `state.blocks` and `state.blocks.hash` in the reducer. This might throw an error if initial state does not define these keys. That is one more reason to compose complex reducers.

Comment: Thank you so much. Feels like this was the piece I was missing to finally understand the spread operator entirely ;)